# Qt: How to notify an object that a signal slot connection involving it has been established

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, signals-slots

I want to make obj_a emit signal_func() immediately after the establishment of the signal slot connection. My question is how can obj_a detect such a connection the moment it was established; does QObject::connect emit a signal when the connection is established?

```
//main function
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  A obj_a; //A is a child class of QObject
  B obj_b; //B is a child class of QObject
  // initialize obj_a, obj_b...
  QObject::connect( &obj_a, &A::signal_func, &obj_b, &B::slot_func ); //how can obj_a detect the establishment of this connection?
  app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do that?  This sounds like an xy problem.  Having said that, signals are public in Qt5 so there's nothing to stop you adding `obj_a.signal_func();` immediately after the `connect` call (although it's probably not considered 'best practice').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) from the Qt documentation, this function return a `QMetaObject::Connection`, which has a method that indicates whether the connection is established successfully or not. You may find [`bool()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html#operator-bool) useful in your case. Just when the boolean is `true` you can do anything with `obj_a`.
I hope this may help you to solve your problem.